# Converting TIFF files to PNG in .Net

Tags: .net, png, tiff

I have to build an application in .Net (3.5) to pick up a TIFF file saved from another piece of software and convert it into a PNG so that it can be rendered easily in Internet Explorer. Does anyone know of any libraries (preferably freeware/open source) that will do this conversion for me?

If there aren't any simple ways of getting it to a PNG are there any libraries that I can use to transform it to another IE friendly image format?

I know I can pass a TIFF to the browser and use a plugin to render it but the PCs this is aimed at are locked down and can't install plugins.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
System.Drawing.
    Bitmap.FromFile("your image.tif")
              .Save("your image.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Please, also check this: [Convert Tiff Images to Gif/Jpeg](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/267798-convert-tiff-images-gif-jpeg)

Comment: Thanks for this it worked first time, you've saved me ages of messing about.

Comment: Works like a charm with simplier streams :)
`System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(tiffStream).Save(pngStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);`

Comment: @Chris I have posted an answer that does work for multi-page tiffs here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24617585/82729

Answer (score 9):

In C# / .NET, it is probably as easy as:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

using (var tiff = new Bitmap("my_tiff_file.tif")) {
    tiff.Save("output.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

If for some reason System.Drawing.Imaging won't read your TIFF files, check out an open-source project called [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), which will read and write just about any image format imaginable. Worst case scenario you'll need to call ImageMagick's convert.exe via Process.Start() in .NET - not elegant, but it does work.

Comment: The question specifically said "to png" though. And it's not a good idea to save to jpeg without specifying the save quality.