# Need a Tiff Viewer Component in .net

Tags: .net

Need a dot net tiff viewer control to integrate with winforms.  The control should allow me zoom and scroll, page up and page down using keyboard shortcuts without actually getting focus.

Answer (score 0):

Havent' found a free one that works well.   On the paid ones [LeadTools](http://leadtools.com) has a product calld RasterImageViewer which is well behaved.  Their support is pretty decent too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post but still can help someone landing here..
I think I had exactly same problem few months back and didn't find much here. But 
anyone else who is trying to achieve the same can go through this
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31247/Multipage-TIF-Viewer

THis is best I found out and really go smooth...If you any other control like rotate,zoom and aetc, that can very easily added..

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and resolved by converting individual pages 'on the fly' to PNG (or other image formats) based on the article ["Convert multipage TIFF to PNG .Net"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566650/convert-multipage-tiff-to-png-net/24617585#24617585) - simply added paging controls to the form. I am not sure about zooming etc, but once you have a single page image, all is possible.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned if you need a free/open source or a paid library. I will suggest you one good but paid library. I have used in past for both asp.net (web and mvc) and windows / winforms based. You can get more information at their site http://www.tiff-viewer.net