# "A generic error occurred in GDI+" Error while showing Images in browser in Windows XP

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, tiff

I am getting following error while showing `.tiff` images in a browser.

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

I am converting `.tiff` images to `.png` and then displaying them in a browser.

My code:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + Request.QueryString["path"]);

Image img = Image.FromFile(Request.QueryString["path"]);               
      img.Save(Context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

However this error only comes up in Windows XP. The same code is works fine in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it using the BitMap

```
System.Drawing.
 Bitmap.FromFile(Request.QueryString["path"])
  .Save(Context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

reference :

[Converting TIFF files to PNG in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566188/converting-tiff-files-to-png-in-net)

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/267798-convert-tiff-images-gif-jpeg